# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '[' --- please explain the error and how to resolve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to form a  matrix from a set of numbers

```
numbers = '''08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48'''
numbers = numbers.strip().split('\n')

x= list(map(int,str(numbers)))

print(x)
```

actual results should ["08, 02, 22, 97 ,38, 15 ,00 ,40, 00 ,75, 04, 05, 07, 78 ,52, 12, 50 ,77, 91 ,08"
"49, 49, 99 ,40 ,17 ,81 ,18, 57 ,60, 87 ,17, 40, 98, 43 ,69, 48, 04, 56, 62 ,00"]
I am trying to form a matrix where i give a command as x[0][0] I should get output as 08

but instead, I am getting an error ---

```
x= list(map(int,str(numbers)))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '['
```

Comment: `x = list(map(int, numbers))` is what you want. `str(numbers)` makes the list a string including those square brackets at the end which later fails doing an `int()` on it.

Comment: @Austin  after executing  " x = list(map(int, numbers)) "  this I am getting an error--x= list(map(int,numbers))

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08'

Comment: If you're trying to get a list of numbers, why are you splitting on `'\n'`? This code makes no sense.

Comment: @Umang, I'm not sure what you need at the end. I guess you have to split by spaces.

Comment: `x=list(map(int,numbers.split()))`

Comment: I am trying to make a matrix. How can I do that ?@melpomene @Austin

Answer (score 1):

What you're effectively doing is splitting the long string of space-separated numbers into a list of strings, then telling Python to format the array as a string and then interpret that as an integer.

If we break it up (I'm using fewer numbers here for brevity):

```
In [1]: numbers = '''08 22
   ...: 49 49'''

In [2]: numbers
Out[2]: '08 22\n49 49'

In [3]: numbers = numbers.strip().split('\n')

In [4]: numbers
Out[4]: ['08 22', '49 49']

In [5]: str(numbers)
Out[5]: "['08 22', '49 49']"
```

As you can see, `str(numbers)` produces a string with the value *['08 22', '49 49']*. When you tell Python to `map` `int` it will effectively do:

```
numbers = [int('['), int('\''), int('0'), int('8'), int(' '), int('2'), int('2'), int('\''), int(','), int(' '), int('\''), int('4'), int('9'), int(' '), int('4'), int('9'), int('\''), int(']')]
```

Which produces your error because *[* can't be parsed as an integer.

What you really want to do is to split again on whitespace and then convert to an integer. This is much easier done with list comprehension than with `map` (which is almost always the case by the way).

```
In [1]: numbers = '''08 22
   ...: 49 49'''

In [2]: numbers = [[int(s) for s in line.split(" ")] for line in numbers.split("\n")]

In [3]: numbers
Out[3]: [[8, 22], [49, 49]]
```

What we do here is that for each row we create a sublist containing all the numbers in that row and gather it up into a list, giving us a matrix:

```
In [4]: numbers[0][1]
Out[4]: 22

In [5]: numbers[1][1]
Out[5]: 49
```

Comment: I did not get this -------                                                                                                              In [2]: numbers = [[int(s) for s in line.split(" ")] for line in numbers.split("\n")]

Comment: It's [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Answer (score 1):

Let's look at what the problem is exactly.
First, you create a large string called `numbers`:

```
numbers = '''08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99...'''
```

If we look at what the result of that creation is (in other words: the contents of `numbers`), we can see that it yielded a string containing newlines:

```
>>> numbers
'08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08\n49 49 99...'
```

So what happens when you do a split on `\n`? Then you get a list of strings, each list containing the numbers up to the next newline:

```
numbers = numbers.strip().split('\n')

>>> numbers
['08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08', '49 49 99...']
```

Casting that list to a string, yields the following:

```
>>> str(numbers)
"['08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08', '49 49 99...']"
```

So when you try to iterate `int()` over that result (`x=list(map(int,str(numbers)))`), it will try to convert that string to integers, character by character.
Since the first character is a `[`, Python will complain about it not being a number.

If you replace `numbers = numbers.strip().split('\n')` by `numbers = numbers.split()`, it will be split on all spaces, newlines and other empty symbols:

```
>>> numbers.split()
['08', '02', '22', '97', '38', '15', '00', '40', '00', '75', '04', '05', '07', '78', '52', '12', '50', '77', '91', '08', '49', '49', '99', ...]
```

Then the only thing left is a simpler map:

```
x= list(map(int,numbers))
```

(Without the casting to `str`)

The result:

```
>>> print(x)
[8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8, 49, 49, 99, ...]
```

Comment: @ T.J.Evers I have edited the question, sorry for the bad communication

Comment: I should note: if you do `int("08")`, you will get `8`, so `x[0][0]` will never return `"08"` if you cast separate values to integers anywhere.
So, assuming you want the string `"08"` and not the number `8`, try:

`x = list(map(lambda x: x.split(), numbers.split('\n')))`

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are applying int function over a strings which has gaps between numbers. casting to int will not work.
I have changed the code slightly and worked around the problems. You may use it.

```py
numbers = '''08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48'''
numbers = numbers.split(" ")
try:
    numbers = map(lambda x: x.split("\n"),numbers)
    numbers = [x[0] for x in numbers]
except:
    pass
x= list(map(int, numbers))
print(x)
```

Hopefully this is what you wanted, else please let me know. The output is as below.

```py
[8, 2, 22, 97, 38, 15, 0, 40, 0, 75, 4, 5, 7, 78, 52, 12, 50, 77, 91, 8, 49, 99, 40, 17, 81, 18, 57, 60, 87, 17, 40, 98, 43, 69, 48, 4, 56, 62, 0, 49, 31, 73, 55, 79, 14, 29, 93, 71, 40, 67, 53, 88, 30, 3, 49, 13, 36, 65, 70, 95, 23, 4, 60, 11, 42, 69, 24, 68, 56, 1, 32, 56, 71, 37, 2, 36, 91, 31, 16, 71, 51, 67, 63, 89, 41, 92, 36, 54, 22, 40, 40, 28, 66, 33, 13, 80, 47, 32, 60, 99, 3, 45, 2, 44, 75, 33, 53, 78, 36, 84, 20, 35, 17, 12, 50, 98, 81, 28, 64, 23, 67, 10, 26, 38, 40, 67, 59, 54, 70, 66, 18, 38, 64, 70, 26, 20, 68, 2, 62, 12, 20, 95, 63, 94, 39, 63, 8, 40, 91, 66, 49, 94, 21, 55, 58, 5, 66, 73, 99, 26, 97, 17, 78, 78, 96, 83, 14, 88, 34, 89, 63, 72, 36, 23, 9, 75, 0, 76, 44, 20, 45, 35, 14, 0, 61, 33, 97, 34, 31, 33, 95, 17, 53, 28, 22, 75, 31, 67, 15, 94, 3, 80, 4, 62, 16, 14, 9, 53, 56, 92, 39, 5, 42, 96, 35, 31, 47, 55, 58, 88, 24, 0, 17, 54, 24, 36, 29, 85, 57, 56, 0, 48, 35, 71, 89, 7, 5, 44, 44, 37, 44, 60, 21, 58, 51, 54, 17, 58, 80, 81, 68, 5, 94, 47, 69, 28, 73, 92, 13, 86, 52, 17, 77, 4, 89, 55, 40, 52, 8, 83, 97, 35, 99, 16, 7, 97, 57, 32, 16, 26, 26, 79, 33, 27, 98, 66, 36, 68, 87, 57, 62, 20, 72, 3, 46, 33, 67, 46, 55, 12, 32, 63, 93, 53, 69, 42, 16, 73, 38, 25, 39, 11, 24, 94, 72, 18, 8, 46, 29, 32, 40, 62, 76, 36, 69, 36, 41, 72, 30, 23, 88, 34, 62, 99, 69, 82, 67, 59, 85, 74, 4, 36, 16, 73, 35, 29, 78, 31, 90, 1, 74, 31, 49, 71, 48, 86, 81, 16, 23, 57, 5, 54, 70, 54, 71, 83, 51, 54, 69, 16, 92, 33, 48, 61, 43, 52, 1, 89, 19, 67, 48]
```

Comment: I have edited the question again, sorry for the bad communication

Comment: I have added another answer below.

Answer (score 0):

In response to your edited question, this is another solution.

```py
import re
numbers = '''08 02 22 97 38 15 00 40 00 75 04 05 07 78 52 12 50 77 91 08
49 49 99 40 17 81 18 57 60 87 17 40 98 43 69 48 04 56 62 00
81 49 31 73 55 79 14 29 93 71 40 67 53 88 30 03 49 13 36 65
52 70 95 23 04 60 11 42 69 24 68 56 01 32 56 71 37 02 36 91
22 31 16 71 51 67 63 89 41 92 36 54 22 40 40 28 66 33 13 80
24 47 32 60 99 03 45 02 44 75 33 53 78 36 84 20 35 17 12 50
32 98 81 28 64 23 67 10 26 38 40 67 59 54 70 66 18 38 64 70
67 26 20 68 02 62 12 20 95 63 94 39 63 08 40 91 66 49 94 21
24 55 58 05 66 73 99 26 97 17 78 78 96 83 14 88 34 89 63 72
21 36 23 09 75 00 76 44 20 45 35 14 00 61 33 97 34 31 33 95
78 17 53 28 22 75 31 67 15 94 03 80 04 62 16 14 09 53 56 92
16 39 05 42 96 35 31 47 55 58 88 24 00 17 54 24 36 29 85 57
86 56 00 48 35 71 89 07 05 44 44 37 44 60 21 58 51 54 17 58
19 80 81 68 05 94 47 69 28 73 92 13 86 52 17 77 04 89 55 40
04 52 08 83 97 35 99 16 07 97 57 32 16 26 26 79 33 27 98 66
88 36 68 87 57 62 20 72 03 46 33 67 46 55 12 32 63 93 53 69
04 42 16 73 38 25 39 11 24 94 72 18 08 46 29 32 40 62 76 36
20 69 36 41 72 30 23 88 34 62 99 69 82 67 59 85 74 04 36 16
20 73 35 29 78 31 90 01 74 31 49 71 48 86 81 16 23 57 05 54
01 70 54 71 83 51 54 69 16 92 33 48 61 43 52 01 89 19 67 48'''
Final_List = []
Final_List.append(re.sub("\n",",",re.sub(" ",",",numbers)))
print(Final_List)
```

The output is as below

```py
['08,02,22,97,38,15,00,40,00,75,04,05,07,78,52,12,50,77,91,08,49,49,99,40,17,81,18,57,60,87,17,40,98,43,69,48,04,56,62,00,81,49,31,73,55,79,14,29,93,71,40,67,53,88,30,03,49,13,36,65,52,70,95,23,04,60,11,42,69,24,68,56,01,32,56,71,37,02,36,91,22,31,16,71,51,67,63,89,41,92,36,54,22,40,40,28,66,33,13,80,24,47,32,60,99,03,45,02,44,75,33,53,78,36,84,20,35,17,12,50,32,98,81,28,64,23,67,10,26,38,40,67,59,54,70,66,18,38,64,70,67,26,20,68,02,62,12,20,95,63,94,39,63,08,40,91,66,49,94,21,24,55,58,05,66,73,99,26,97,17,78,78,96,83,14,88,34,89,63,72,21,36,23,09,75,00,76,44,20,45,35,14,00,61,33,97,34,31,33,95,78,17,53,28,22,75,31,67,15,94,03,80,04,62,16,14,09,53,56,92,16,39,05,42,96,35,31,47,55,58,88,24,00,17,54,24,36,29,85,57,86,56,00,48,35,71,89,07,05,44,44,37,44,60,21,58,51,54,17,58,19,80,81,68,05,94,47,69,28,73,92,13,86,52,17,77,04,89,55,40,04,52,08,83,97,35,99,16,07,97,57,32,16,26,26,79,33,27,98,66,88,36,68,87,57,62,20,72,03,46,33,67,46,55,12,32,63,93,53,69,04,42,16,73,38,25,39,11,24,94,72,18,08,46,29,32,40,62,76,36,20,69,36,41,72,30,23,88,34,62,99,69,82,67,59,85,74,04,36,16,20,73,35,29,78,31,90,01,74,31,49,71,48,86,81,16,23,57,05,54,01,70,54,71,83,51,54,69,16,92,33,48,61,43,52,01,89,19,67,48']
```

Please let me know if this is what you wanted.

Comment: re.sub is replacing space with comma what I want is a 2d grid

Comment: This response was in your requirement that you posted. You have written the following. "actual results should ["08, 02, 22, 97 ,38, 15 ,00 ,40, 00 ,75, 04, 05, 07, 78 ,52, 12, 50 ,77, 91 ,08" "49, 49, 99 ,40 ,17 ,81 ,18, 57 ,60, 87 ,17, 40, 98, 43 ,69, 48, 04, 56, 62 ,00"]" If you really want to create a 2D grid of numbers then just below this comment is the solution (that I gave first time). Please let us know what you intend to do with the result.

Comment: thank you for the help. I am just practising. This is one of the Euler problems.